# Strategy for Managing Large Resource Website in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msdeploy

I am in the process of migrating a series of sites which had previously been managed essentially with no version control (there was VSS plugged into the development server, but from the developer's POV it was essentially non-existant) over to TFS with WebDeploy installed on a Windows Server 2012 machine for deployment.

My problems are coming from a couple of sites we have with extremely large resource libraries, we are talking 20-30GB each of PDFs, PowerPoints and videos.

Under the past set-up these resources would basically live only on the server.  The site developer would get a new set of document, package them up ship them off to the server with FPSE and then delete their local working copy to free up space.

With TFS I have just made a copy of the current state of the site, loaded into the solution and put it all in TFS.  The result is unwieldy for a number of reasons:

1. It means the solutions are huge and we are quickly running into space issue on our local machine, plus for a new developer loading the solution, or for a developer coming back to the solution after deleting their local copy the initial open can take hours as all those large resources are downloaded from the server.
2. When doing a publish all these resources are included in the package which gets stored on the users machine.  This leads to even more space being used up and an extremely long initial publish as all the resources get copied over to the temp directory.

I have thought about adding skip rules to the deployment settings so that only additions and updates are processed, and then having the developers delete the documents after publishing which would work but it leaves us with a version control that is only a partial copy of the true contents of the site.

Is there a way to configure these directories so that they need to be explicitly copied locally, i.e. when a user opens the solution from TFS they don't get copied, but they are available if we ever need to do a clean deployment of the site to a whole new server?  This in combination with the skip rules would be a solution, but I have no idea if/how it is possible.

One additional caveat, these are website not web application projects which always seems to make things just a bit more difficult...

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you workspace mappings look like?  Can you simply cloak these large files?  Better still if they're all in the same directory, and you can simply cloak the directory?

Comment: At the moment the entire repository is mapped at the root to a source directory on my local machine.  Quick Google search for cloaking makes it look like it could be exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're storing non-essential binaries alongside your application code.

This is a huge problem for the following reasons:

- Automated builds take longer, so it's harder or impossible to set up decent continuous integration.
- Deployments take longer, because they have to copy around gigs of irrelevant files
- Developers have to deal with downloading tons of files that just aren't relevant to them in order to do their work

Break the two things apart. Store content somewhere else. The "somewhere else" is up in the air, depending on a lot of factors. For starters, you can just migrated it to a separate folder, outside the folder of your application code. Developers who aren't concerned with content can cloak the folder. That said, **source control is a really bad place for static, binary content.**

Something like this:

```
$/
  Dev
    Application
      Code
      Content        
  Main
     etc
```

Developers can map $/Dev/, and just cloak $/Dev/Application/Content. 
Deployment becomes a bit trickier if you do this, because you have an extra step -- deploying code and deploying content become separate tasks. The idea is to just combine the /Code and /Content folders.

This gives you great flexibility, though, since you can deploy your application's code faster. You can also take steps to automate your content deployment, so that content changes can get pushed out more quickly, without having to worry about a content push taking your site down while you deploy new code.